Ngx-mat-select-search: Can't click anything but 'ALL' in my select menu
I'm currently trying to implement a search function in my mat-select menu in Angular 18, through ngx-mat-select-search. I'm able to successfully click when I click 'ALL' after I search 'ALL'. However, I've hit a roadblock when trying to essentially click any of the other modules in the menu. Specifically, it doesn't let me click them at all. Any pointers? Here is my HTML:
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="matformfield">
    <mat-label class="matlabel" *ngIf="!selectedModules.length">Select Modules</mat-label>
    <mat-select #drop multiple [(ngModel)]="selectedModules"> <!--[(ngModel)]="selectedModules"-->
        <ngx-mat-select-search [formControl]="control" ></ngx-mat-select-search>
        <!--<input (keyup)="onKey($event)">-->
        <mat-select-trigger *ngIf="drop.value && drop.value.length">
            {{ drop.value.length === modules.length ? 'ALL' : drop.value}}
        </mat-select-trigger>
        <!--<mat-option class="matoption" (click)="onClick(drop.options, true)" [value]="'ALL'">ALL</mat-option>-->
        <mat-option class="matoption" *ngFor="let module of filteredRecords | async" [value]="module" [disabled]="isAllSelected() && module !== 'ALL'" (click)="onClick(drop.options, module === 'ALL')">{{ module }}</mat-option>
        <!--[value]="module.value", {{ module.viewValue }}-->
    </mat-select> 
</mat-form-field>

And here is my typescript:
export class ModuleMenuComponent {
  /*modules: [
    { value: 'Module 1', viewValue: 'Module 1'},
    { value: 'Module 2', viewValue: 'Module 2'},
    { value: 'Module 3', viewValue: 'Module 3'},
    { value: 'Module 4', viewValue: 'Module 4'},
    { value: 'Module 5', viewValue: 'Module 5'}
  ];*/
  public control: FormControl = new FormControl();
  private _onDestroy = new Subject<void>();
  public filteredRecords: ReplaySubject<any[]> = new ReplaySubject<any[]>(1);

  @ViewChild('Select') select: MatSelect;

  modules: any[] = [
    'ALL', 'lorem', 'ipsum', 'domor', 'sit', 'amet'
  ];
  selectedModules: string[] = [];

  constructor() {
    this.setInitialValue();
    this.control.setValue([]);
    this.filteredRecords.next(this.modules.slice());

    this.control.valueChanges
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._onDestroy))
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.filterModulesMulti();
      });
      
  }

  private setInitialValue() {
    this.filteredRecords
      .pipe(take(1), takeUntil(this._onDestroy))
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.select.compareWith = (a: any, b: any) => a === b;
      });
  }

  private filterModulesMulti() {
    if (!this.modules) {
      return;
    }

    let search = this.control.value;
    if (!search) {
      this.filteredRecords.next(this.modules.slice());
      return;
    }
    else {
      search = search.toLowerCase();
    }
    if (search.length >= 2) {
      this.filteredRecords.next(
        this.modules.filter(module => module.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1)
      );
    }

    
  }

  /*onKey(value) {
    const input = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    this.selectedModules = this.search(value);
  }

  search(value: string) {
    let filter = value.toLowerCase();
    return this.modules.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().startsWith(filter));
  }*/

  clearFields() {
    this.selectedModules = [];
  }

  isAllSelected(): boolean {
    return this.selectedModules.includes('ALL');
  }

  onClick(options:QueryList<MatOption>, isFirst:boolean=false) {
    if (isFirst) {
      const el = options.first;
      options.forEach((x) => {
        x[el.selected ? 'select' : 'deselect']();
      });
      if (el.selected) { //new
        this.selectedModules = this.modules.slice();
      }
      else {
        this.selectedModules = [];
      } // end new
    }
    else {
      const selected = options.filter((x, index) => index && x.selected);
      if (selected.length == this.modules.length - 1) { 
        options.first.select();
        this.selectedModules = this.modules.slice(); 
      }
      else {
        options.first.deselect();
        this.selectedModules = selected.map(x => x.value);
      }
    }
  }
  
}



Any pointers would be appreciated for this problem. I've also attached a gif to demonstrate the issue.

Issue 1: You have to place the <ngx-mat-select-search> element in the <mat-option> element.
<mat-select #drop multiple [(ngModel)]="selectedModules">
    
  <mat-select-trigger *ngIf="drop.value && drop.value.length">
    {{ drop.value.length === modules.length ? 'ALL' : drop.value}}
  </mat-select-trigger>
    
  <mat-option>
    <ngx-mat-select-search [formControl]="control"></ngx-mat-select-search>
  </mat-option>
    
  <mat-option
    class="matoption"
    *ngFor="let module of filteredRecords | async"
    [value]="module"
    [disabled]="isAllSelected() && module !== 'ALL'"
    (click)="onClick(drop.options, module === 'ALL')"
    >{{ module }}</mat-option
  >
</mat-select>


You are using template variable named "drop" but in ViewChild you are referring "select" which results the select will be undefined.

@ViewChild('drop') select!: MatSelect;


As you are referring to the <mat-select> element from the view, you can't place your logic within the constructor. The select variable will only be initialized during the AfterViewInit event. Also, you should need the ChangeDetectorRef to resolve the Expression Changed After Checked
error.

constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.setInitialValue();
  this.control.setValue([]);
  this.filteredRecords.next(this.modules.slice());
  this.cdr.detectChanges();

  this.control.valueChanges.pipe(takeUntil(this._onDestroy)).subscribe(() => {
    this.filterModulesMulti();
  });
}

Demo @ StackBlitz
